# Drag and drop files onto desktop icon in C++ WinForms

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm a beginner in C++ and I'm writing a simple windows forms application. I was wondering if it would be possible to implement passing dropped files as arguments, like in console applications. With the latter, it's simply a matter of using the **argc** and **argv[]** parameters in **main()**, but obviously this can't be done in a winforms application (at least not directly).

From what I gathered when searching the web, it seems that it's possible to do in C#. However, I'm not willing to translate my program into C#, as I have no experience with that language. Please note that I'm not interested in making a form accept dropped files as arguments, but the desktop icon specifically.

So my question boils down to the following: Can you pass dropped files as starting arguments in a C++ winforms application?

Comment: It is not you, it is OS who is responsible for passing files as command line args. You can only consume those args in your application. And as long as it is .net, you can use `Environment::GetCommandLineArgs()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new Win32 C++ project, in your main .cpp file there is a wWinMain function which is where the application starts. You have a pointer to a string there with the command line arguments (which will be your drag/dropped file path). See my code and comments below, I assume you know what to do with argv and argc.

```
#include <shellapi.h>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);


    // lpCmdLine is your command line arguments
    int argc;
    LPWSTR* argv = CommandLineToArgvW(lpCmdLine, &argc);

    // Now you have argc and argv[] to do with what you want
```

Comment: Thank you. So, I have to switch to a Win32 project and WinForms is a no-go in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're stuck on C++ but any executable can take command line arguments. Use whatever language you're comfortable with, personally I prefer C# .NET